# Any news about plans for a movie of "Startide Rising"?

Tags: startide-rising

Anybody know what the current status is of plans to make a movie of *Startide Rising*? Has anything changed with the status in the past couple years? Can someone light a fire under an appropriate rump to get this project underway!

Comment: I can see Startide Rising has the potential to make a great sci-fi film, given a large budget to cover creature effects for multiple alien species (+ anthropomorphic dolphins and a chimp!) and dazzling FX for vast space battles. One obstacle may be viewers may not want to sit through a movie where the protagonist's spaceship is stuck on a planet for repairs. Including scenes for the discovery of the derelict space fleet would be cool, which got scant mention in the book as I recall.

Comment: I can't see it happening any time soon. Almost all the exposition is in people's heads and the idea of trying to get audiences excited about dolphins on a spaceship is enough to send most studios running in the opposite direction

Comment: I never did completely buy into the rational for humans uplifting dolphins and chimps, aside from the cool factor of having talking dolphins and chimps in a book. The film would have to explain that a bit so the viewers are all on board with suitable suspension of disbelief.

Comment: @RobertF - Any film that requires thirty minutes of exposition before the audience understands what's happening is doomed from the word 'go'. Just look at Dune for a perfect example of this.

Comment: Yes it is - although Virginia Madsen was delightful eye candy when I was 13 years old. :) BTW I felt Dune was film with too much whispered internal exposition - very distracting.

Comment: I think Startide Rising would make a great film.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez - Paramount disagree with you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Variety Magazine](http://variety.com/1998/film/news/neufeld-buys-uplift-series-1117481566/)), an option to make a TV Series of the "Uplift" book series was purchased by Mace Neufield with the intention of securing funding from Paramount.  A pilot screenplay was written by Trevor Sands in 1999 following an [extensive consultation](http://www.sloan3d.com/brinl/srmovie.html) with fans of the book series but ultimately the project failed to attract Hollywood funding and the *'option'* has [since lapsed](http://www.sloan3d.com/brinl/srmovie.html);

> *"Roland Emmerich has, after a few months of consideration, **officially passed** on "Startide Rising". Kel Symons, head of development at Mace
>   Neufeld, is still determined to find it a home (**in spite of the fact
>   that the option has expired**).*
>
> *We are discussing an "off the books" polish of the script, which he plans to submit to various studios and directors in the hopes of
>   getting someone to renew the rights to the material and eventually
>   bring it to the screen."*

As to the current status, David Brin's [website](http://www.davidbrin.com/startiderising.html) contains an open link requesting that anyone interested in securing the film or TV rights should contact his manager; Vince Geradis. This would strongly suggest that there's no reasonable chance of seeing this on the big/small screen in at least the next couple of years.

Comment: Correct, but this is not any new information regarding the project. I'm specifically asking if something new has happened in the past couple years.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez - Yes, the option has lapsed. That's new info.

Comment: Richard is correct. You should accept this answer. I looked into it myself not two weeks ago.

Comment: @Richard. It's not clear in your answer the timeframe of the option lapsing. On the wikipedia link, the only reference on the film version is from 1998. I'm looking for new information that's within the past 2 years. If you can provide some recent reference that would be cool.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez - I've updated with a 2001 quote from Trevor Sands stating that the option has expired.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez - Also, for the record they weren't considering a film. It looks like Paramount passed on the pilot for a TV series.